# Wygwam for EE v2.5.2

Tags: add-on, wygwam, pixelandtonic, wysiwyg

I have tried to install the Wygwam 2.7.1 add-on module to my existing EE. When I go to edit or publish content through a channel that hasthe Wygwam as a field... it just looks like a regular textbox and not the usual awesome Wygwam tools I'm used to seeing... any ideas? If I try to remove the field type so I can re-install, it will delete ALL of my data...

Comment: Check your browser's console for any JS errors that may be occurring.

Answer (score 1):

First thing’s first; check to make sure you have the `themes/third_party/wygwam` folder in its place. I can’t tell you how many times I’ve accidentally uploaded the `system` folder instead. After that, I would suggest you use your developer tools in your browser to see if JavaScript is failing to load, and if so, where it’s being requested from.